# 「そこで泳ぐことがありますか」or 「そこで泳いだことがありますか」

Tags: grammar, tense

I'm asked to complete the following sentence with the appropriate inflected form of the verb:

[image: img1]

The book provided a translation: "Have you ever had a swim there?" This indicates experience as far as I can tell, so my answer is the following:

> そこで泳**いだ**ことがありますか

However, the book answer is `泳ぐ`

[image: img2]

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I thought the construction was `~たことがある`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

～したことがある means "have done" with the focus on the thing at issue having happened in the past or having a certain experience.

～することがある means "occasionally/sometimes do", focusing instead on the action being a possible occurrence.

For the grammar point, see, for example, [this](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2019/05/09/jlptn4-grammar-kotogaaru/) and [this](https://j-nihongo.com/dic-kotogaaru/).

そこで泳ぐことがありますか means "Do you swim there?" or more literally "Does it ever happen that you go there for a swim?" Since the English sentence is "Have you ever had a swim there?" You got it right. I think it should be そこで泳いだことがありますか

Comment: +1, I also believe 泳いだことがありますか is the correct answer.